# Hide params in url by asp.net mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an asp.net mvc 2 application. I get a page with the url `http://localhost/Object/ChangeObject/108?MtRid=216584`. I want to route it like this: `http://localhost/Object/ChangeObject`. 
How to write a route for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one way to do this:

1. Try to modify the methode **"application_beginrequest"** of **"Global.asax"** This method is called every time some request is made to the website.
   Take a look at [this example](http://issuesdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/07/url-rewriting-making-user-friendly-urls.html)
2. URL Routing - By adding custom URL Route mapping rules before the default one as described in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{MtRid}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, MtRid = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
                );
```